# Identifying specific characters in an image using tesseract in R?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am attempting to identify and remove specific characters in ECG image files. In ECGs, the "words" that appear are not usual English words, but lead names like "aVR", "V5", "II". Here is an example image:

[image]

I am trying to use the `tesseract` package in R to identify and remove all characters/numbers in these images so only the ECG lines are left. This is what I've tried:

```
eng <- tesseract("eng")
ECG_signs1 <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = "V1V2V3V4V5V6aVRaVLaVF"))
ECG_signs2 <- tesseract(options = list(tessedit_char_whitelist = "V1"))

tes.data1 <- tesseract::ocr_data ("processing_image.png", engine = eng)
tes.data2 <- tesseract::ocr_data ("processing_image.png", engine = ECG_signs1)
tes.data3 <- tesseract::ocr_data ("processing_image.png", engine = ECG_signs2)
```

But the resulting tibbles have no rows, ie tesseract won't identify any characters in these images.

I'm not sure what else to do as the text seems very clear in the image, the contrast is high, and the noise is low... I'm happy to use any other OCR library available for R. I deeply appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Are these images in a PDF file? If so, could you provide a link to this PDF file? Also, are you able to improve the quality of the image you made available? The quality of the image is important when we use an OCR to detect characters.

Answer (score 0):

### Characteristics of these images:

1. The parts we want to keep (the ECG lines) are [mostly] horizontally-connected strands of pixels.
2. The parts we want to erase (the text) are small, isolated clumps of pixels.

### An Approach

1. Use the `imager` package to get the shape of each blob in the image
2. Erase blobs having an [Area, Width, Height, ...] smaller than some threshold

```
# --- Load packages
require( purrr )
require( imager )
require( tibble )
require( dplyr )

# --- Configure
cfg <- list(
    DATA_PATH = 'path/to/image/files'
)

# --- Get an image for experimentation
im <- load.image( file.path( cfg$DATA_PATH, 'D6VDQ.png' ))

# --- Convert to gray scale
gs <- grayscale( im )

# --- Remove very light marks
px <- threshold( gs )

# --- Extract contours
ct <- contours( px, nlevels = 2 )

# ---------------------
# --- Utility functions
# ---------------------

gross_width <- function( i ){
  ( max( ct[[ i ]]$x ) - min( ct[[ i ]]$x ) )
}   

gross_height <- function( i ){
  ( max( ct[[ i ]]$y ) - min( ct[[ i ]]$y ) )
}   

# --- Calculate the overall width and height for each blob
widths  <- seq( ct ) %>% map_dbl( gross_width  ) %>% round( 0 )
heights <- seq( ct ) %>% map_dbl( gross_height ) %>% round( 0 )

# --- Consolidate the information about the blobs into one place
blobs <- tibble(
    id = seq( ct )
  , x = seq( ct ) %>% map( ~ct[[ .x ]]$x )
  , y = seq( ct ) %>% map( ~ct[[ .x ]]$y )
  , gross_width = widths
  , gross_height = heights
  , gross_area  = widths * heights
)

# --- Try an arbitrary threshold to see what happens
cfg$MAX_WIDTH  <- quantile( blobs$gross_width  )[ 4 ]  # Third quartile
cfg$MAX_HEIGHT <- quantile( blobs$gross_height )[ 4 ]  # Third quartile

# --- A function to conditionally erase a blob
erase_small_blobs <- function( i ){
  if( (  widths[[ i ]] <= cfg$MAX_WIDTH  ) &
      ( heights[[ i ]] <= cfg$MAX_HEIGHT )   ){
    color.at( im, ct[[ i ]]$x, ct[[ i ]]$y ) <<- c( 1, 1, 1 )
  }
}

# --- Process all the blobs with the selective eraser
seq( ct ) %>%
  walk( erase_small_blobs )

# --- Show the results
plot( im )
```

[image: Cleaned image]

### Evaluate

This first attempt took out all the text, except a single 'T' near the third heartbeat of the top trace, perhaps because it is too close to the trace to be it's own blob.